# Story With Character Named Briar

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to remember a young adult series I read perhaps 15 years ago, but I don't remember many details. One of the characters was named Briar. As I recall, there are four main characters that channel elemental power, and they have a meditation routine to unlock this power where they inhale and exhale to a seven count. Sorry it's not much to go on, I will try to add more details if I remember any.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandry%27s_Book

Comment: Love the profile pic :-D *Dovie'andi se tovya sagain!*

Comment: I'm just here because this question reminded me of [the Bone series](http://boneville.wikia.com/wiki/Briar_Harvestar).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like [Sandry's Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandry%27s_Book) by Tamora Pierce

> Niklaren (Niko) Goldeye finds Lady Sandrilene fa Toren, Trisana
>   Chandler, Daja Kisubo, and Briar Moss, four young misfits from four
>   different classes, and brings them to Winding Circle Temple in Emelan.
>   They find themselves housed together as they did not "fit in" when
>   they slept in the dormitories for everyone in Discipline Cottage to
>   learn and use their new-found magical abilities. All four have ambient
>   magic, as opposed to academic magic, and the power they use comes from
>   ordinary things all around them. Sandry has magic with threads, Tris
>   with weather, Daja with smithing, and Briar with plants.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for the *[Circle of Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_Magic)* books by Tamora Pierce.

There are two quartets (as Pierce is prone to writing books in sets of four) and a final stand-alone book to wrap up the series.

The first quartet starts with the books:

- *Sandry's Book*
- *Tris's Book*
- *Daja's Book*
- *Briar's Book*

The second quartet, *[The Circle Opens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Circle_Opens)* continues their stories as they venture out into the world.